# Many to Many relationship: how to exclude a row by its foreign row

Tags: sql, postgresql

simple_restaurant

```
+--+------------+
|id| restaurant |
+--+------------+
|1 |restaurant1 |
|2 |restaurant2 |
|3 |restaurant3 |
+--+------------+
```

simple_category

```
+--+-----+
|id|name |
+--+-----+
|1 |ham  |
|2 |salad|
+--+-----+
```

category_restaurant_relation

```
+--+-----------+-------------+
|id|category_id|restaurant_id|
+--+-----------+-------------+
|1 |1          |1            |
|3 |1          |2            |
|4 |2          |3            |
|5 |2          |1            |
+--+-----------+-------------+
```

I want to exclude all restaurant which have category 'ham', so the result should be 'restaurant3' only

```sql
SELECT sr.*
    FROM simple_restaurant sr
    JOIN (
            select distinct restaurant_id
            from simple_category_restaurant_relation crr
            WHERE crr.category_id NOT IN (1)
        ) as valid_category_restaurant
          ON sr.id = valid_category_restaurant.restaurant_id
```

I tried this query but the result was
restaurant1 and restaurant3.

What is the correct query?
(I'm using postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

Join the three tables together, aggregate by restaurant, and then assert that ham never appears on the menu:

```sql
SELECT sr.id, sr.restaurant
FROM simple_restaurant sr
INNER JOIN category_restaurant_relation csr
    ON csr.restaurant_id = sr.id
INNER JOIN simple_category sc
    ON sc.id = csr.category_id
GROUP BY
    sr.id,
    sr.restaurant
HAVING
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE sc.name = 'ham') = 0;
```

### Demo

Comment: I didn't know `FILTER(WHERE ..)`. Is it product specific?

Comment: @Cid The OP clearly mentioned Postgres...not sure whence your confusion is.  `FILTER` has been part of Postgres for years at this point.

Comment: I missed the part about pgSQL

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can find restaurant ids which are in category 1. (inner query)
Then, you can find restaurants which are not in inner query's list.

```
SELECT sr.*
    FROM simple_restaurant sr
    WHERE sr.restaurant_id NOT IN (
            select restaurant_id
            from simple_category_restaurant_relation crr
            WHERE crr.category_id IN (1)
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Select restaurants id which have category id as 1 and use NOT IN restaurant ids

```
SELECT sr.restaurant
FROM simple_restaurant sr
where sr.restaurant not in (select distinct restaurant_id
        from category_restaurant_relation crr
        WHERE crr.category_id NOT IN (1)) ;
```

Comment: The result was `restaurant1, restaurant2, restaurant3`

Answer (score 0):

One way to select all restaurants that don't have the ham category is to use `not exists`

```
select * from simple_restaurant sr where not exists (
  select 1 from category_restaurant_relation crr
  join simple_category sc on sc.id = crr.category_id
  where crr.restaurant_id = sr.id
    and sc.category = 'ham'
)
```